# Attempting to get the rolling mean per group, getting wrong values and "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I seem to misunderstand and misuse `pd.Series.rolling.mean()`. I have a toy `df` here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.choice(['x', 'y'], 8),
    'b': np.random.choice(['r', 's'], 8),
    'c': np.arange(1, 8 + 1)
})
```

```
   a  b  c
0  y  s  1
1  y  r  2
2  y  s  3
3  y  r  4
4  y  s  5
5  x  r  6
6  y  r  7
7  x  r  8
```

I do this grouping operation:

```
df['ROLLING_MEAN'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].rolling(3).mean()#.values
```

That doesn't work. I get:

> TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

For some reason, when I uncomment the `.values` method, it works, but if I isolate one group, it doesn't have the intended effect.

```
df[
    (df['a'] == 'x') &
    (df['b'] == 'r')
]
```

```
   a  b  c  ROLLING_MEAN
0  x  r  1           NaN
2  x  r  3      2.666667
3  x  r  4      4.000000
4  x  r  5      5.666667
7  x  r  8           NaN
```

How can there be a rolling mean value of `5.666` while no number that high has even been seen yet?

Here is my expected output:

```
   a  b  c           ROLLING_MEAN
0  x  r  1                    NaN
2  x  r  3                    NaN
3  x  r  4      ((1 + 3 + 4) / 3)
4  x  r  5      ((3 + 4 + 5) / 3)
7  x  r  8      ((4 + 5 + 8) / 3)
```

Comment: this post may help ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75346172/rolling-unique-value-count-in-pandas-across-multiple-columns/75348952#75348952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the output of `df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].rolling(3).mean()` this is:

```
a  b   
x  r  3         NaN
      4         NaN
      6    5.333333
   s  1         NaN
y  r  2         NaN
      5         NaN
   s  0         NaN
      7         NaN
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

The extra levels make it incompatible with the original df.

You can use [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) so it has the behavior you want:

```
df['ROLLING_MEAN'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c']
                        .rolling(3).mean()
                        .droplevel(['a', 'b'])
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  ROLLING_MEAN
0  y  s  1           NaN
1  y  r  2           NaN
2  y  s  3           NaN
3  y  r  4           NaN
4  y  s  5      3.000000
5  x  r  6           NaN
6  y  r  7      4.333333
7  x  r  8           NaN
```

Comment: Dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996302/how-to-use-rolling-functions-for-groupby-objects#comment83741185_41191278)?

Comment: @BigBen I didn't know this Q/A, this looks similar indeed, although no answer seem to suggest this approach. Edit: actually the question is more on how to perform a rolling at a time when this wasn't a well known method, I think this question is more focused on this specific issue.